# Access Append Queries: I'm shown two warnings every time I execute the query. Disabling warnings hides both of them. I'd like to have just one

Tags: ms-access, append, warnings, ms-access-2016

Every time I try to run an append query, Access likes to warn me that doing so will make irreversible changes to the data. This is good; I like being able to confirm if I want to make irreversible changes.

However, every time I run them, Access gives me ***two*** warnings back-to-back.

[image]
[image]

Now, I followed the instructions to disable confirmation messages, however it disables ***both*** of these messages. I'd like to keep one of them, but showing two is annoyingly redundant.

Is there a way to disable the first ***or*** second messages only?

Comment: Not that I know of. So offer users your own message to confirm if they want to proceed.

Comment: How are you running the query? Macro? VBA? Navigation Pane?